# c# , Regex ,textblock accepts only numbers and , '+' , '-'

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I did this so it accepts only numbers and I want it to also use the  -,+ operators for numbers under 0:

```
e.Handled = new Regex("[^0-9]+").IsMatch(e.Text);
```

Comment: This pattern `[^0-9]+` matches 1 or more occurrences of any char except a digit 0-9. What do you mean by `-,+ operators for numbers under 0`?

Comment: i mean i need all numbers , .....-2,-1,0,1,2,3... above and below 0

Answer (score 0):

Some characters in Regex as part of the syntax both + and - and part of this, to escape them you need to use the \ character.

```
^\-?[\d]+$
```

Now this looks for any number that could possibly start with a - and then any number of digits, and must end in a digit.

Something like RegexR is a good tool to use to build Regex:
https://regexr.com/

Comment: how do i use it , if i replace it with the string("^\-?[\d]+$") it sends error - unrecognized

Comment: e.Handled = new Regex("^\\-?[\\d]+$").IsMatch(e.Text);

Comment: The minus (`-`) character does not need escaping, it is not a special character. Perhaps you are confused by its use within character classes.

Comment: e.Handled = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+").IsMatch(e.Text); this is working for me thx